# SOAP Delphi имя выходного параметра

Tags: delphi, soap

Пишу на Delphi SOAP-сервер. По спецификации у него должна быть функция, которая возвращает версию сервера, наподобие такого:

```
function TMySOAP.GetVersion: string; stdcall;
begin
  Result := '1.0';
end;
```

По спецификации имя выходного параметра функции должно быть Result, то есть в WSDL должно быть описано так:

```
<message name="GetVersion3Response">
  <part name="Result" type="xs:string"/>
</message>
```

Но в Delphi слово 'Result' используется для своих нужд, поэтому оно изменяется и у моего сервера WSDL выглядит так:

```
<message name="GetVersion3Response">
  <part name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</message>
```

Проблема в том, что клиентские программы работают по спецификации, в которой имя выходного значения "захардкожено", все они ожидают в ответ имя Result.

Как выйти из данной ситуации? Возможно ли как-то указать Delphi, чтобы он возвращал значение в поле с именем Result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался сам, так работает нормально:

```
procedure TMySOAP.GetVersion(out Result: string); stdcall;
begin
  Result := '1.0';
end;
```